# Read Properties.Settings.Default from a different project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, configuration, settings

In my `WPF MVVM` application, I have `Model`, `View`, and `ViewModel` as a separate projects. Now, in my `View` application I have user settings defined in `Settings.settings` file, I can access them through:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MySettingName
```

and in my Tool.exe.xml I can confirm that the setting is there:

```
<userSettings>
    <Tool.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="MySettingName" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
    </Tool.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Now the question is how do I access those settings from my ViewModel project? 
It's obvious that if I were to do `Properties.Settings.Default.*` it will point to it's own settings.

So far I tried to do the following two ways:

```
Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
KeyValueConfigurationCollection settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;
```

and

```
var keys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys;
```

But both of them always return 0 entities.

I also know that I can create a `ViewModel` and bind settings from the View, but for this particular case, creating a new `ViewModel` just to access setings sounds a little bit overkill.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you are using visual studio you can change the access modifier for the settings class to public. Double click the Settings.settings file and there is a drop down at the top. You can then access the settings using the full namespace

Comment: A better way would be to provide a service that wraps the settings using `SettingsBase`

Comment: Can you give a bit more details on a service?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/632161/1729349

Here's how I was able to access the value of the setting:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// find section
ClientSettingsSection configSection = config.SectionGroups[@"userSettings"].Sections["Tool.Properties.Settings"] as ClientSettingsSection;

var setting = configSection.Settings.Get("MySettingName").Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
```

Comment: looked good, but i still only get the default values instead of the values from the config file :-(

Comment: NVM .. i am just stupid. 
Visual studio overwrites the config file everytime on build if building another linked project.

Answer (score 0):

AppSettings is for the 'default' appSettings configuration section. You need to open your own configuration section. Try this:

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings");
```