# Get path to config file which is stored in AppData

Tags: c#, settings

I have to read app setting file and get some value from another my application. My settings class is located in a separated asembly, but when I try to get value:

`var id = MyAppSettings.Default.UserId`

I get default value which is equal 0. I understood that setting file is 'exe' specific. Setting file is stored in
`%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\<Company Name>\<appdomainname>_<eid>_<hash>\<version>\user.config`

I tried to get path and have found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629143/how-to-write-to-the-main-exes-config-usersettings-section/632161#632161). But this code also return 0(my default value), because it looks config file in the local folder.

How to properly read setting file (not app.config and local)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, if user.config file is accessible to your user and you have permission to read this file ::

```
 string path=@"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\<Company Name>\<appdomainname>_<eid>_<hash>\<version>\user.config"
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
        //and then access setting and so on....
```