# ConfigurationManager - How to read a value from .exe.config

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

i'm working on an app that allow users to manage windows programs.

So i have a .exe.config file and contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="Control_Desk.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<userSettings>
    <Control_Desk.Properties.Settings>          
        <setting name="enabletw" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="enablelivemail" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="enabledesktop" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="enablelogmein" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="enableps" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="enablecorel" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="enablescanner" serializeAs="String">
            <value>False</value>
        </setting>
    </Control_Desk.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

And i want to read and change the valeus, but, no sucess, no changes are saved and i cant read any value, when i try, the program throws a System.NullReferenceException, here is my code:

```
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        if (config.AppSettings.Settings["enablelivemail"].Value == "True")
            {
                config.AppSettings.Settings["enablelivemail"].Value = "False";
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
                //ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            }
            else
            {
                config.AppSettings.Settings["enablelivemail"].Value = "True";
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(config.AppSettings.SectionInformation.Name);
            }
```

So, on second line i got the exception and nothing works, any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11149569/3583859 Please refer this, will help

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje, did you try the solution for the OP's use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.AppSettings` on 2nd line reads from `<appSettings>` node in config file. And there is no `<appSettings>` node on your config file.

Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629143/how-to-write-to-the-main-exes-config-usersettings-section) to solve your problem.

Comment: You need to begin explaining the solution, where a separate Section Group and Section are created, since `userSettings` is not a standard group and `Control_Desk.Properties.Settings`, not a standard section